# Replacing text in header of google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

Hi I'm using google sheets to create a quote by replacing text in a google doc. This works well in the body of the document, but not in the header. The code im using is given below.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Quote Menu'); // Wrap the menu name in quotes
  menu.addItem('Create EN/IT Quote', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addItem('Create EN + IT Quote', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addItem('Create EN Quote', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addItem('Create IT Quote', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addToUi(); // Add parentheses to call the addToUi function
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('file id');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1folder id');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Quote Data');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  


  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Offer ${row[11]}. ${row[12]} - ${row[3]}` , destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const header = doc.getHeader();
    
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    
    header.replaceText('{{EN12}}', row[11]) 
    body.replaceText('{{EN1}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN2}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN3}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN4}}', row[3]);

  
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
  })
}
```

add more details and more charchters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that your script `header.replaceText('{{EN12}}', row[11])` can be used to the header. But, from `but not in the header`, I guessed that you might have enabled the 1st-page header. Because when the 1st page header is enabled, `header.replaceText('{{EN12}}', row[11])` cannot be used. If my guess is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `createNewGoogleDocs()` as follows.

```js
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('file id');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1folder id');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Quote Data');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Offer ${row[11]}. ${row[12]} - ${row[3]}`, destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();

    // --- I modified the below script.
    const document = body.getParent();
    let s = null;
    while (s = document.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION, s)) {
      s.getElement().asHeaderSection().replaceText('{{EN12}}', row[11]);
    }
    // ---

    body.replaceText('{{EN1}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN2}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN3}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{EN4}}', row[3]);
    doc.saveAndClose();
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, `replaceText('{{EN12}}', row[11])` can be used with both the 1st page header and other page headers.

Comment: This works perfectly. Ive added some more lines to 's.getElement().asHeaderSection().replaceText('VAL1', row[##])